# Change Data Capture (Async Apex Trigger) vs @future method in Trigger

Tags: trigger, future, change-data-capture, async-trigger

What is the difference between using the **Async Apex trigger** and **@future methods**? Why use **Async Apex Trigger** when we have **@future method** **to separate the thread** from the main Trigger?

The only difference I can think of is that CDC could be utilised as a PUB/SUB event.

---

**ChangeEvent Triggers (Async Apex Trigger)**

```
trigger AccountCDCTrigger on AccountChangeEvent (after insert) {}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

CDC and future methods address quite different concerns. Note, however, that CDC can be seen as a flavour of Platform Event, and if you bring that into the question you get a much more interesting set of constraints and approaches.

Up to 50 future method invocations can be initiated from a synchronous transaction, while only 1 can be generated from an async transaction, and zero from a future method.

You can perform DML on up to 10000 records in a given transaction, with a trigger called with up to 200 records at a time. You can also perform up to 150 DMLs in a transaction. And that transaction could itself already be async. If your trigger logic tries to use a future method, it will break in all sorts of scenarios because you will exceed the number you can enqueue (e.g. you update 201 records in an async transaction - this will call your trigger twice, which will try to initiate a future each time, exceeding the async limit of 1).

I suggest you read [this article](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) on why not to use future from a trigger, and how you can efficiently use platform events instead. The article has a link to sample code, but there is also [this github repo](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-callout) with a slightly different approach.